# Check that product with those values does not already excist

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

In a WebAPI project i have the follwing controller;

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostProduct(Product product)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Products.Add(product);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(product);
    }
```

based on this model

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
public int ExternalId { get; set }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductType IncidentType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Manufacture> Manufactures { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller, i want to make a check, before it saves the product, that checks that the ExternalId togethr with the ProductTypeId does not excist already.
Meaning, there should only be one product, that has the ExternalId of 123 togethr with the ProductTypeId of 23.

How do i add this check, to my controller above?

Comment: You can use a remote validator. Here is an angular/web api example: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AngularJS-with-Web-API-8210527d

Comment: @SteveGreene thx. But as i read the example, they rely on a frontend, to actually make the check (title excist in their example), and if true, then post to the api. I do not have that option, in my case, as this api is open to users, so they are able to post directly to it, from their own apps. therefore i can not have a validation check in the frontend, as i have no frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostProduct(Product product)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if(db.Products.Any(x => x.ExternalId == product.ExternalId && x.ProductTypeId == product.ProductTypeId))
    {
        return Conflict();
    }

    db.Products.Add(product);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(product);
}
```

Although I wouldn't recommend in having that kind of logic in your controller.

Comment: Where else would you have this logic in a public facing API?

Comment: I would move the logic to some other class that the controller could use. Maybe implementing an `IRequestHandler` with https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR. This way the only job for the controller would be to validate the modelstate and return the correct httpstatus code.